# is there a way to create custom event and dispatch events on classes in cocos creator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cocoscreator

how do I create custom events in cocos creator? I tried creating a singleton class and using the instance to addEventListener, but that didn't work.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in diferent ways, but on of the more effectives, how can goes over differents nodes are:

```
cc.game.emit("specialEvent", eventParamenters);
```

and in your listener script:

```
cc.game.on("specialEvent", (eventData)=> { ...doSomething... } );
```